# Order applications on the Windows 8 taskbar?

Tags: windows, windows-8

I like to have my open applications ordered like so on the taskbar:

1. They are all to the right of the icons
2. They are in an order I specify, e.g. Intellij first, then Chrome, then Virtualbox.

Obviously I can order these myself but it's annoying - is there some kind of tool that will do this for me?

Example:

[image]